# Binding event to chosen select

Tags: jquery, onchange, jquery-chosen, jquery-events

I have this code for a select box which is being displayed by the Chosen jQuery plugin. What I am trying to achieve is to get the value from the current item that has been selected:

```
<div>
  <select id="schedule_event" name="schedule[event]" style="display: none; " class="chzn-done"><option value="Game" selected="selected">Game</option>
    <option value="Event">Event</option>
    <option value="Training">Training</option>
  </select>
  <div id="schedule_event_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-active" style="width: 854px; ">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single chzn-single-with-drop" tabindex="-1">
      <span>Game</span>
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <div class="chzn-drop" style="width: 849px; top: 27px; left: 0px; ">
      <div class="chzn-search">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 814px; " tabindex="0">
    </div>
    <ul class="chzn-results">
      <li id="schedule_event_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected highlighted" style="">Game</li>
      <li id="schedule_event_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">Event</li>
      <li id="schedule_event_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">Training</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript I'm using at the moment to find the current value is:

```
$("#schedule_event").chosen().change( function() {
    alert(+ $(this).text());
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

However, I keep getting a 'NaN', ie no value.

Comment: why is there a plus in `+ $(this).text()`?  Also you alert for text but use val.

Comment: @JosephMarikle - I thought it was an issue too, but apparently that just "casts" `004` to `4`. Tats_innit's demo showed it works.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Code:**

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() {
    alert(+$(this).val());
    //$('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

**Demo:**

<strike>Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MM7wh/</strike>

#### Edit  (6th July 2015)

cdns are changed now.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uk82dm5L/

Please use `$(this).val()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: got this to work, though had to change my values into int, as the text didnt seem to conform

Comment: going on one further from this, how would I check what value is preselected on loading the page? do i use `$('select.chzn-done option:selected').val();` ? or is there a better, easier method

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane you are correct, thats right! http://api.jquery.com/val/ **sample code:** `$('select.foo option:selected').val();`

Comment: $('select.foo').chosen().val(); also gets the selected value when loading the page.

Comment: It is important to only run this function when the document is ready. Also, the selector ".chzn-select" should aim at the original select, rather than the one generated by Chosen.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I prefer use this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#mychosen', function(evt, params) {
    if (params.selected != undefined)
    {
        console.log('selected: ' + params.selected);
    }
    if (params.deselected != undefined)
    {
        console.log('deselected: ' + params.deselected);
    }
});
```