# Chosen plugin change event not triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, onchange, jquery-chosen, jquery-events

I'm using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) jQuery plugin and noticed that the `change` event is working **only** when the page loads, **NOT** every time the `input` field is being change.

How can I make it work every time the user changes the value of the input field?

Here is my code:

```
 $("#day").chosen().change({
     console.log('working');
  });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This answer contains a working solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279898/binding-event-to-chosen-select

Answer (score 28):

To fire the standard change event, use like:

```
  $('#day').on('change', function(e) {
    // triggers when whole value changed
    console.log("value changed");
  });
```

To fire the event on each key press,

```
  $('#day').on('keyup', function(e) {
    // triggers when each key pressed
    console.log("key pressed");
  });
```

To know about the default events of chosen, refer [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html).

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("selector").chosen().change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
    });
})
```

Comment: It's worked for me, I could console the value..  
   

                                                             
  `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("selector").chosen().change(function (event) {
            console.log($(event.target).val());
    });
})`

Answer (score 7):

**Updating Chosen Dynamically**

If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "chosen:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content.

```
$("#foo").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP question

Answer (score 1):

**chosen multiple**

When chosen multiple is set, `$(this).val();` returns an `array`.
The following code will return the last id [un]selected:

```
$('#my_chosen_list').chosen().change(function(_, object){
    console.log(!object.selected ? object.selected : object.deselected);
    ...
});
```

tip: `undefined` is undefined (...), but `!undefined` is true, so `!!undefined` is false

Answer (score 0):

Then Write it in keyup event of input:

```
$('inputselector').keyup(function() {
  $("#day").chosen().change({
   console.log('working');
  });
});​
```

and on dom ready:

```
$('inputselector').trigger('keyup');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Asp.net dropdown listbox
  <asp:ListBox ID="CompanySelect" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
  AutoPostBack="true"   
  data-placeholder="Select Companies" class="chosen-select"  SelectionMode="Multiple" 
  EnableViewState="true" Height="39px" Width="99%" >
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">All</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:ListBox>

    //This code help me for hiting chozen change event.

     $('#chosen').val('').change()
        {
           alert("working");
        }

    //if you want to get select value you need to do this.

     $('#chosen').val('').change()
        {
            alert($(".chosen-select").val());
        }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.